# Texture paint problem

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

Why i cant painting using texture ? it showing only color. I think about stencil brush mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to effect the mesh you need to make sure the texture is loaded in the material. To paint onto it in cycles you need to make sure the image node exists in the node material and to have it effect the render it needed to be wired up.